# Printing a html in a Maui Blazor app running on Android not working

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, maui-blazor

I have a Maui-Blazor app and I want to print a html (modal). The app should allow the user to print to PDF or any other format. The app runs inside Android.

I am using the following package for printing: https://github.com/Append-IT/Blazor.Printing.

However, when I run the app on Android, the print functionality does not work. I am not sure what the problem is and I would like help resolving this issue.

In Windows, printing works perfectly, but on Android, Do nothing

I have been searching for a solution to print a PDF or HTML in a Maui Blazor app running on Android. I came across a link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/914868/how-to-print-pdf-html-in-maui) that suggests using the WebView class, but it does not provide a clear example of how to implement this in .NET and Blazor-Maui.

How can I use the WebView class to print a PDF or HTML in a Maui Blazor app running on Android? Can anyone provide a clear example or guide on how to implement this in .NET and Blazor-Maui?

or there is  better opition  ?

Comment: Did you check the log files? https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/understanding-logging  The link you provided has a documentation section and in documentation has sample code.  We need to narrow down exactly what is failing.  Without more info we would be guessing.

Comment: ok i try to find the log file and edit question